# how to deploy gulp app on heroku directly from github repo

Tags: node.js, heroku, github, gulp

I want to deploy an app at heroku.com for testing purpose.

My app using task runner gulp for creating web-server and automatically injecting scripts and bower_components.

The files structure of my app is :

```
app/css/
app/patrials/
app/scripts/
app/index.html
bower.json
package.json
gulpfile.js
```

How can I deploy this app to heroku

[github.com/osamasaeed/ngOpenWeather](http://github.com/osamasaeed/ngOpenWeather)

Thank you in advance!